# Behaviour of io.ReadAt() at the end of input source

Tags: go, file-io

I have a program that constantly reads bytes of a input file, in 1MB ranges, after initially splitting the file into multiples of this ranges, i.e. 'n' window ranges. The source file is of type `*os.File` and I use [ReadAt](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderAt) method from the `io` package to read at the specific start address of each window.

The problem is, when reading towards the end of the file, e.g. in the last window, though the file is still within the range, I get `EOF` errors. When I looked up the go.dev documentation for the same, it says

> If the n = len(p) bytes returned by ReadAt are at the end of the input source, ReadAt may return either err == EOF or err == nil.

It is not clear, under what circumstances it would return `nil`, because I keep getting EOF, even when I'm still reading within the range. Why does this happen and how to avoid this situation?

Or I should use [io.SectionReader](https://pkg.go.dev/io#SectionReader) for this case?

Not able to produce a MCVE for this scenario. Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the n = len(p) bytes returned by ReadAt are at the end of the input source, ReadAt may return either err == EOF or err == nil.

This quote relates to the [`ReaderAt.ReadAt()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReaderAt) method:

```
ReadAt(p []byte, off int64) (n int, err error)
```

You pass a slice to read into, and an offset to read at (from). The method returns the number of read bytes and an error. The quoted part means if the passed slice is fully read and this operation exhausted the input (meaning the end is reached), `err` may be `nil` or may be `io.EOF`. This is implementation dependant, you should write code that does not depend on what a concrete implementation returns.

In practice this means if `io.EOF` is returned, you know right away there are no more inputs. If `n == len(p)` and `err == nil`, this just means you don't know *yet* whether there are more data to read or not, you have to call `Read()` or `ReadAt()` again, which will read 0 bytes (`n == 0`) if there are no more data, and this time `err` will surely be `io.EOF` (given no other error occurs).

Documentation of `ReaderAt.ReadAt()` also states that:

> When ReadAt returns n < len(p), it returns a non-nil error explaining why more bytes were not returned. In this respect, ReadAt is stricter than Read.

This means if `ReadAt()` can't fill `p` completely from the source (e.g. because its end is reached before `len(p)` bytes could've been read), `ReadAt()` will return a non-`nil` error which will be `io.EOF` (if the cause is that the end of source was reached).

As this second quote states: `ReadAt()` is stricter than `Read()`, `ReadAt()` will try to fill the passed slice (similar to [`io.ReadFull()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadFull)). So you should only use [`io.SectionReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#SectionReader) if it makes your code more readable or it gives you convenience (e.g. if you do not want a 1 MB buffer to read that part in one step, `io.SectionReader` may make that code simpler), otherwise it won't give you much.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I realized I wasn't checking the the value of `n` at all. Will make a quick test upon the values of `n` and `len(p)` and post my findings here.

Comment: Just perfect! Fixed my implementation to handle the EOF as indicated. Thank you!